# What is the difference between regular quit and eclipse terminate?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

What happens is that when I press ALT+F4(Win) or CMD+Q(Mac) to quit the program, the program will hang until I force quit it using task manager.

However, when I terminate the program using eclipse's terminate button, the program shutdowns nicely without hanging.

**What is the difference between the two methods of closing the application?**

*For example, is it because threads in the application do not terminate on its own when we do a regular quit (i.e. ALT+F4) whereas in eclipse, threads are "forced" to terminate?*

> ### Edit
>
> I just realised `System.exit(0)` is equivalent to "force quit" (i.e. no hangs). Is there any method where I can detect when ALT+F4 or CMD+Q is pressed and from there, the system/ program will do a `System.exit`?
>
> ### Edit 2
>
> I have done the following but the hang still persists:
>
> 1. I have tried changing all of my threads into Daemon.
> 2. I have used *jvisualvm* to see which threads are still running after `ALT+F4` is pressed. I do realise some "Pool-i Thread-i" threads are still running. (*Is there any way to pin-point which part of the codes represents "Pool-i Thread-i"*? I suspect these threads are created by one of the third-party libraries I have used.)
> 3. In my threads/ callables, I have a console output at the very end of the thread and the console output will display when I `ALT+F4` the program. For example,

```
public Void call() {
    while(true) {
        
    }
    System.out.println("Thread has finished");
}
```

> The console will print "**Thread has finished**" when I press `ALT+F4`, hence I assume these threads have terminated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse terminate button performs basically what force quit in Task Manager does -- it terminates the process forcibly. Alt+F4 or CMD+Q notifies the program to be terminated, which should response in a timely manner; if it doesn't, you'll get the unresponsive program alert in Windows.

Comment: How do I identify what is the cause of the unresponsiveness? (If you are going to recommend `jvisualvm`, can you elaborate on 'how'?)

Comment: Can you post the code of the application you are running? You mentioned threads, so one thing to check would be checking if any threads you have created got terminated; if they are supposed to be daemon threads (threads that should terminate when the JVM terminates), be sure to make it as such (by calling thread.setDaemon(true);

In Eclipse, actually, it's a bit simpler; run your application in Debug, and you should be able to see the threads running. When your application is supposed to terminate, there should be no non-daemon threads running.

Comment: I am sorry I can't post any codes here as it's really a very huge chunk. I have edited my post to show what I have tried on my end. Thanks for your reply. I will try the eclipse Debug method soon

Comment: It seems like a thread pool is being used, and isn't disposed of properly; When you look at the stacktrace of the thread in the thread pool (Pool-i Thread-i), you might be able to find out what's running in it and make sure that is disposed of properly.